# npm sxa command installation error

Tags: sxa-cli, npm

I am using Visual Professional 2022, with Sitecore 10.0
I am trying to install SXA for themes. But when I run the command

```
npm install -g @sitecore/sxa-cli --force
```

It's installing the required files and deleting them after that. Can anyone help me in fixing this issue [image]

Comment: What do mean under "and deleting after that"?

Comment: please check the node and npm version

Comment: @Rameshkumar the node Version is 20.9.0 and npm version is 10.1.0

Comment: Anton its installing the required files under the folder @Sitecore located at  under the C driver app folder and deletes all the required file under the same folder